# 64 duplicate symbols for architecture armv7s when adding admob to my app

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, admob

64 duplicate symbols for architecture armv7s
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Not sure if anyone has had this issue and fixed it. Thank you all in advance for your help.

Answer (score 4):

I had similar scenario with admob & i was pulling my hair for 2 days until I figured it out the hard way but thanks to that I have a better idea how it works. You can solve this by adding linker flags to each valid architecture separately.

[image]

You can see here that I've added separate linker flags for armv7s architecture & I removed "-all_load" for that. Other architectures (armv6 , 7, etc) gets compiled with -all_load where armv7s is not. Even-though this question is few months old I hope someone would find it useful.

Comment: Thank you so much! Without your help I would have probably abandoned AdMob altogether as I could not it get it to work on the device.